# How to Change Title Attribute to be different from Page title

Tags: title

My Wordpress Site (PeterKellner.net)'s home page is a page titled "Who is Peter Kellner".  The browser tab shows that and I want it to just say peterkellner.net.

How can I make that happen without changing the actual title shown on the page?

Comment: You can use Yoast SEO plugin. It has the field to set the title tag

Comment: That worked, but it changed it for all my pages. I'm assuming that the title is good for SEO. I just want the home page not to have title of that page, not all the others? Anyway to change the title for just one page?

Comment: Yoast has global settings for all titles, and allows change the title of each page individually.

Answer (score 1):

Please try installing the Yoast SEO plugin. It has an option to add a custom title for the page without changing the title. Let me know if it works or not.

:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yoast SEO WordPress plugin, which provides additional custom fields to add the page title and meta description.

Yoast SEO: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

[image]